# Push Notification Alternatives

Tags: iphone, cocoa, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I heard that push notification is not reliable. What could be the alternative for this?

The use case I am trying to handle is:
1. I have a app which will be shared by three kind of groups. Each group contains certain set of persons.
2. A request is submitted by first kind of group and it will be serviced by second kind of group. So, all persons who are part of second group should be notified and no one apart from them should get the notification.
3. Similarly, A request is submitted by first kind of group and it will be serviced by third kind of group. So, all persons who are part of third group should be notified and no one apart from them should get the notification.
4. Even second group persons can submit a request to third group.

Please provide your thoughts as how should I handle these scenarios.

Comment: Who told you that push notification are not reliable? If they aren't reliable, there's probably an error in you code...

Comment: We have coded Push Notifications in couple of projects and at times it does not turn up with notification on time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Push notifications rely on the network (3G/WiFi) presence to deliver the notification. Also, there is no response back from the Apple Push Notification Server which guarantee the delivery of the notification. Having said all these things... iPod touch is higly unreliable for delivery of notification because one, it do not have 3G; second, for saving battery its notifications are internally turned off for some time....

One Alternative to this is to keep polling the server in a background thread for any modification. But this will work only when app is running.

Another Alternative can be writing our own APNS kinda infrastructure.

Comment: Small correction: Not the notifications are turned off, the WiFi is turned off when the device is in standby. It only activates WiFi every few minutes to check for new notifications, mails etc.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question well.  I was building an app that required notifications to be delivered in a timely fashion, our "solution" was to restrict the app to iPhones only (specifically, devices with telephony), and put a ton of disclaimers all over the place.  Tough problem to truly solve, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

you're right to say Push Notifications are not reliable.
For one thing, if the device is not connected to the internet, APNs only keeps one push notification to be sent when the device connects again (the last notification sent from the provider). Since there's no way to determine if a notification has been already sent or not after your servers sent them to APNS, you can't even try to queue the notifications on your end.

Other than that if your app depends on PN the user can easily break it's functionality by turning notifications off.

So you're absolutely right, if the data you want to send is critical, then you shouldn't use Push Notification. But I believe there's really no solution to your problem. you simply can't rely on them for your app to work.

I think the best approach would be like the email app for example, where you can download your emails when you start the app wether you have PN turned on or not, and the PN just notify you of new email, even though it's not guaranteed you'll get it at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternative, since Apple does some very low level communication. You would need to work together with the mobile providers to build something like the notification services.

That said, I don't think the service is not reliable. Maybe you should check your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that APNs does not guarantee delivery: From their [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html), they say that:

> **Important**: Because delivery is not guaranteed, you should not depend
>   on the remote-notifications facility for delivering critical data to
>   an application via the payload. And never include sensitive data in
>   the payload. You should use it only to notify the user that new data
>   is available.

Comment: I'm digging the grave commenting here, but since delivery is not 'guaranteed', especially within a short amount of time (I've had APNS delayed 5-10 minutes), how can you guarantee critical data is delivered without polling a server, burning bandwidth and battery life?